# Is sending requests from a mobile frontend app to a backend api https url, fully secure?

Tags: security, encryption, mobile, https

I am developing a mobile app with flutter. The app will also communicate with my backend.

I will be sending data from the frontend to the backend and responding from the backend to the frontend. I am concerned about the possibility of malicious third parties changing/altering the data contained in the request. Whether it be a response from the backend to the frontend or a request from the frontend to the backend.

Is an API https url that I send requests to enough to prevent this scenario or man in the middle attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Https (TLS) protects against man-in-the-middle attackers that have access to the network traffic (third parties). Such an attacker, even if they managed to gain access to the communication channel will not be able to read or alter the transmitted data (and still keep it valid and undetected). They will be able to tell the fact that there *is* traffic (and the endpoints, ie. the client and your backend), and can also guess relatively accurately the amount of data transmitted.

However, it does not prevent legitimate users (having access to a client) from viewing/altering what is sent or received, neither does it protect traffic from an attacker that has already compromised your backend. A valid user (or an attacker that already compromised either the client or your server) will be able to transmit anything they want. This means they can send anything to your server, and can alter the response before it reaches your client.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, sending data to a https url (frontend to backend), will prevent someone from altering the data being sent. But I also have to worry about someone intercepting my response from the backend to frontend and changing data.

Comment: No, traffic itself is protected both ways. But the user itself can alter either the sent or the received data. Or an attacker that already compromised the client. Or the server. Think of TLS as a pipe. The pipe itself is secure, but it has two open ends.

Comment: Ok, if all I care about is that the clients data is not changed by anyone but themselves before it reaches the server and that my server response is not changed by anyone but my server then all I need is https. That said, Could someone sit at the end of the pipe, on the client side, receive my response and then send the client their own response?

Comment: I can probably use ssl pinning to solve the “third party intercepting messages at the client side and sending client their own response” problem?